# How are Selenium logs accessed in the ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am using `browser.driver.manage.logs.get :browser` to get browser logs using `selenium` with `watir`.

However, when I look at the docs, `#manage` on `Selenium::WebDriver::Browser` returns an `Options` object. See [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver).

`Selenium::WebDriver::Options` does not have a `log` method, but yet on the GitHub page there is a `log()` method, see [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html).

Is this experimental in the ruby gem? Where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a the documentation for gem version 0.0.28. The latest version is 3.0.1 found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Options). The GitHub page for the `log()` method that you shared is for the Java language bindings. The GitHub page for the Ruby language bindings is [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Options.html)

Keep in mind that logs are not available for every browser, and they are not yet defined in the [W3C WebDriver Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/)